# Why loading text doesn't show in vue js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

I have like this code in my app:

```
<div id="app">
  <button v-if="!isLoaded && !isLoading" @click="startLoading()">Start Loading</button>
  <div v-if="isLoading">Loading app...</div>
  <template v-else>
    <img v-show="isLoaded" ref="img" />
  </template>
</div>

<script>
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
      isLoading: false,
      isLoaded: false,
    }
  },
  mounted() {
     
  },
  methods: {
    startLoading() {
      this.isLoading = true;    
      
      for (let i = 1; i < 1E9; ++i) {
         //Dummy load;
         const a = 1;
        }
      this.isLoading = false;   
      this.isLoaded = true; 
        
      this.$refs.img.src = 'https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2018/07/04/11/58/xiamen-3515964__340.jpg';
    }
  },
})
</script>
```

In this code, when you click on the "Start Download" button, the message "Loading..." should appear for a while, after which the image will appear. But there is no sign "Loading". Why? Can this be fixed? If so, correct it. (It is undesirable to remove the dummy load. Imagine that we are there very intensively processing some file for the user)

Answer (score 1):

If the code execution has to wait for the loop to finish, mark `startLoading` as `async` (so you can use `await` inside of it) and use `await` on whatever promises your loop awaits. Basic example:

```
methods: {
  async startLoading() {
    this.isLoading = true;    

    for (let i = 1; i < 1E9; ++i) {
      const a = await // your promise here;
      // do stuff with `a`
    }
    this.isLoading = false;   
    this.isLoaded = true; 

    this.$refs.img.src = 'https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2018/07/04/11/58/xiamen-3515964__340.jpg';
  }
}
```

Docs and examples [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function).

Comment: I must use like this code inside `created` hook? `window.addEventListener("load", () => { this.isLoadind = false});` or where I must set loading `false` correctly in my code? @tao

Comment: I must show image when loop is finsih. While not finish must be shown loading text

Comment: You obviously expect the loop (which probably contains some promises) to delay the execution of the code after it when those promises resolve. If you're not showing the contents of the loop, how do you suggest I help you?

Comment: In this code, when you click on the "Start Loading" button, the inscription "Loading ..." should appear for a while, after which the image will appear. But there is no “Loading” sign. Why? Can this be fixed? If so, correct it. (It is undesirable to remove Dummy load. Imagine that we are there very intensively processing some file for the user)

Comment: Without showing the for loop contents I can't help you more.

Answer (score 0):

You could use events `onload` and `onerror`:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <!-- button -->
    <button v-if="!isLoaded && !isLoading" @click="startLoading">Start Loading</button>
    <!-- during loading -->
    <div v-show="isLoading && !isLoaded">Loading.....</div>
    <!-- image show when loaded -->
    <img 
      :src="imgSrc" 
      v-show="isLoaded" 
      @load="imgLoadedHandler" 
      @error="imgFailedHandler" />
  </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      imgSrc: '',
      isLoading: false,
      isLoaded: false,
    }
  },
  methods: {
    startLoading() {
      this.isLoading = true;
      this.imgSrc = '...';
    },
    // called when image loaded
    imgLoadedHandler() {
      this.isLoaded = true;
      this.isLoading = false;
    },
    // called when image failed to load
    imgFailedHandler() {
      this.isLoaded = true;
      this.isLoading = false;     
    }
  }
}
</script>
```